# Cloud Firestore not saving data flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm learning Flutter and as an exercise I'm interfacing with Firebase (I'm also new to this - my first encounter).
In the exercise when we register a new user we create a document for the newly registered user with default values.

A new user is getting registered but neither collection nor document is getting created.

I had created the Cloud Firestore is Test Mode. I've attached the rules bellow.

```
Rules :
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 3, 4);
    }
  }
}
```

auth.dart

```
//Resgister using email and password
  Future registerWithEmailPassword(
      {@required String email, @required String password}) async {
    try {
      Firebase.UserCredential resut = await _auth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      Firebase.User user = resut.user;

      //create a new document for user with uid
      await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData(
        sugars: '0',
        name: 'new crew member',
        strength: 100,
      );
      return _userFromFirebase(user);
    } catch (e) {
      //print(e.toString());
      return e.toString();
    }
  }
```

database.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class DatabaseService {   final String uid;   DatabaseService({this.uid});   
//colection reference   
final CollectionReference brewCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('brews');


  Future updateUserData({String sugars, String name, int strength}) async {
    return await brewCollection
        .doc(uid)
        .set({'sugars': sugars, 'name': name, 'strength': strength});   } }
}
```

I added a break-point and checked the data in updateUserData, the data is proper.

Comment: In you `DatabaseService` class, `brewCollection` is commented out!

Comment: @ASADHAMEED, that was the problem when I pasted my code in the stack-overflow's editor. I checked the code final CollectionReference brewCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('brews'); is not commented and the problem is building.

Comment: What do you want to return from updateUserData?

Comment: @RehmatSinghGill, Currently I wish to return nothing. Later I will try to bool with status of update.

Comment: your code looks good; have you got any exceptions in `catch` block?

Comment: Could you comment out your `try/catch` statements in your code? Also in your Firebase rules replace `if request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 3, 4);` with `return true;`. Start testing and uncomment 1 by 1 to pinpoint areas that requires fixing.

Comment: MuthuThavamani reas, Thanks for the exception hint. I was getting MissingPluginException exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their was an issue with the Firebase plugin.

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DocumentReference#set on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_firestore)
```

I updated by `pubspec.yaml` to have the latest version file then run the following commands

```
flutter clean
flutter packages get
```